# Use of weak-reference in Java EE application

Tags: java, weak-references, thread-local

I have the following code:

```
Object obj = new Object();
ThreadLocal<Object> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Object>();
WeakReference<Object> weakReference = new WeakReference<Object>(obj);
threadLocal.set(obj);
```

My question is that in a Java EE application, when we use weak-reference, is there any need to explicitly call `ThreadLocal.remove()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not call remove, the `ThreadLocal` will maintain reference to the `WeakReference`, but this will not prevent `obj` from being garbage collected.

Comment: Read this article : https://gist.github.com/chrisvest/32c691e51f891a35a1ca. As per my understanding, No need to explicitly call ThreadLocal.remove() method.

Comment: @vikash Your test confirms exactly what I wrote.